# Choppy motion of ROS controlled yaskawa robot

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, motoman, joint-trajectory-action, motoman-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to manipulate  a **GP8 yaskawa** robot through **motoplus**.  My work is based on [Motoman](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman) reperotory. The communication with the robot is started with robot_interface_streaming_gp8.launch of package motoman_gp8_support. I have no problem with the communicating my computer with robot.

Every time I send a new trajectory goal, the real robot **starts moving**. However, its **motion is not continuous**. It **decelerates** at some points and **makes some stops** *before achieving goal*. An finally, it acheaves the desired goal.

I looked into the motoman [driver wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver). It was mentioned that " The interface does provide some low-level filtering, however. Sudden stops or breaks in the trajectory stream result in smooth deceleration on the physical robot hardware. "

More information:

**ROS version**: ROS Melodic

**Computer operation system**:  Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

**motoman git**: kinetic-devel branch

**Controller**: yrc1000

**Installation MotoROS**: Yaskawa did it for me.

**Start command**:

```
roslaunch motoman_gp8_support robot_interface_streaming_gp8.launch robot_ip:=*. *. * .*  controller:=yrc1000
```

Then I run a ROS node which publishes my two-point trajectory into "/joint_trajectory_action topic".

**Trajectory generation**: I send a goal trajectory of type [control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal](http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/control_msgs/html/msg/FollowJointTrajectoryGoal.html). It is composed of **two points** whose velocities are zeros. This goal is sent to the "**/joint_trajectory_action**" topic. First trajectory point corresponds to the actual behaviour of the robot. It is got from /joint_states topic. Second point is defined by the user respecting the acceptable range limits. Typically, I send the second point using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller

**Connection**: The controller is connected to the computer by ethernet.

I need to know please the cause of the motion discontinuity. Can it be done because of the trajectory non-filtering before sending it to action topic? If yess, how can I filter a trajectory of type control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal?? Are there some ROS filters for control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal?

According to you, is there another cause of the choppy motion I am getting?

I am so thankful for your help and advices.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370444/choppy-motion-of-ros-controlled-yaskawa-robot/) by [baklouti-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/62010/baklouti-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2021-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-27**:
I believe we'd have an easier time figuring this out if you could post on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/issues) about this.

Please include relevant details, such as:

- which controller do you have
- version of the system software
- how you've installed MotoROS (did you do it, did Yaskawa do it for you)
- which version of MotoROS you are using
- how you start everything (ie: which `.launch` files)
- how you are generating your trajectories
- show an example trajectory you're submitting as a goal to the driver
- capture the network traffic between your ROS PC (the one running `motoman_driver`) and the Yaskawa controller (use Wireshark for this)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-27**:
Finally: please mention you've posted on ROS Answers first in your issue.

And post a comment here with a link to your issue on the issue tracker.

That way we keep things connected.

**Comment by [baklouti-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/62010/baklouti-s/) on 2021-01-28**:
I updated my subject. Thank you

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-28**:
Where is your post on the `ros-industrial/motoman` issue tracker? I don't see it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-28**:\

> Trajectory generation: I send a goal trajectory of type control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal. It is composed of two points whose velocities are zeros. This goal is sent to the "/joint_trajectory_action" topic. First trajectory point corresponds to the actual behaviour of the robot. It is got from /joint_states topic. Second point is defined by the user respecting the acceptable range limits.

please don't describe your trajectory.

Copy-paste the *message* which is sent to the driver.

> Typically, I send the second point using rqt_joint_trajectory_controller

Creating trajectories using code will be much more reproducible. The `rqt_joint_trajectory_controller` is not a good testing tool, nor a good way to control a robot deterministically.

> Then I run a ROS node which publishes my two-point trajectory into "/joint_trajectory_action topic".

if you have a ROS node, show us the code.

But again: please do this on `ros-industrial/motoman`, not here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-28**:
Why did you delete your question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-29**:
Have you solved your problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-02**:
This will be my last comment on your question.

I'd like to make sure you've solved your problem, even if it turned out to be not a problem, but something misunderstood for instance.

I'd appreciate it if you could post a comment here to confirm things are now working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn Thank you for your interest for my subject. The main problem was the use of rqt_joint_trajectory_controller , which sends non continuous trajectory points.

---

Originally posted by [baklouti-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/62010/baklouti-s/) with karma: 30 on 2021-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-02**:
Thanks for reporting back.